# How to find both the maximum data value and the corresponding timestamp stored in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there a way to find out the timestamp of the maximum data value in Apache IoTDB? How should I write the SQL query statement to not only find out the maximum values of certain time series and the time of these values?

Answer (score 0):

Apache IoTDB contains selector functions and `TOP_K` parameter can return `k` data points with the largest values in time series. The result will also contain the corresponding timestamp of the maximum values.